# How to use OpenMP in Rcpp when calling functions from headers?

Tags: r, openmp, rcpp

I have created many functions that I want to called in my current .cpp script. As usually, I do it by calling the headers (eg: my_function.h). The issue is that when I want to use OpenMP, my R session blows-up.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include "my_function.h"
using namespace Rcpp;

#ifdef _OPENMP
#include <omp.h>
#endif

NumericMatrix m_shortwave_extra(NumericMatrix latitude,
                                NumericMatrix longitude,
                                double time_zone,
                                double year,
                                double month,
                                double day,
                                double time,
                                NumericMatrix slope,
                                NumericMatrix orientation,
                                double S = 1364.0,
                                int threads = 1){
      
      int n_it  = latitude.ncol();
      int n_row = latitude.nrow(); 
      
      NumericMatrix shortwave_out(n_row, n_it);
      
      #ifdef _OPENMP
            if ( threads > 0 )
              omp_set_num_threads( threads );
      #endif
      
      #pragma omp parallel for
      
      for(int i = 0; i < n_it; i++){
               
        shortwave_out(_, i) = 
               my_function (latitude(_, i),
                            longitude(_, i),
                            time_zone,
                            year,
                            month,
                            day,
                            time,
                            slope(_, i),
                            orientation(_, i),
                            S);
      }
      
      return shortwave_out;
      
}
```

I would like to know what I am doing wrong when using OpenMP (the routine works fine when I am not parallelizing).

Comment: What is the contents of **my_function.h**?

Comment: You could consider trying some of the OpenMP examples at the RcppGallery as _e.g._ the [faster multivariate Normal densities](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/dmvnorm_arma/).  We don't seem to have a truly minimal beginner example.  And don't forget about the OpenMP plugin to enable it.

Comment: I will work in some minimal working example but since it is a big project, my_function.cpp also depends on other headers (header_1.h and header_2.h) and so on...I want to ask if any limitation exist regarding the number of nested headers? @StéphaneLaurent

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do in one of my packages. First, here are the contents of the ***Makevars*** file:

```bash
PKG_LIBS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)
CXX_STD = CXX11
PKG_CXXFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)
```

To set the number of threads (`unsigned int nthreads` in my code), I do:

```cpp
#ifdef _OPENMP
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(nthreads)
#endif
```

this directive is then followed by a `for` loop.

This is all I have related to **openmp** in my code, and this works.

I think you don't need to do a check for `threads > 0`. Just use `threads = 1`.

Comment: Yes. And via a file used with the `Rcppp::sourceCpp()` helper function this gets added automatically for you via the `// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]` plugin.

Comment: It didn't work...I added the Makevars file and the number of threads, but when using more than one thread session blows-up...any other idea? @DirkEddelbuettel

Comment: Please construct a [minimally complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Nobody can you help you based on just "it didn't work".

Comment: I will work in some minimal working example (@DirkEddelbuettel) but since it is a big project, my_function.cpp also depends on other headers (header_1.h and header_2.h) and so on...I want to ask if any limitation exist regarding the number of nested headers?